# Use Ajax Calendar with Master Page in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using Master Page in my Project and the problem is in using 
ajax calendar exterder in my content page,

if i use calendar extender it gives  the error like:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Looking forward for ur valuable solution........

Thnx in Advance,
Supriya

Comment: You are getting error when only Ajax calendar is there?

Comment: yes it's only in case of calendar extendar,even i have use maskededitextender too there but no probs in that.

Comment: There could be a myriad of reasons for this.  Is the control that the calendar extender targets on the content page too?

Answer (score 0):

There Must be code behind error. Check error about assigning values. You may need to cast the value.

Comment: i am using just in design view,have not done any coding in reference of that.

Comment: Then you must share your design code here. else i won't be able to get your error.